# What are valid values to use in Jack Henry's CustAdd API for a customer's email address?

Tags: soap, jackhenry-jxchange

When calling the CustAdd API to add a new customer record to Silverlake, I receive error 112 stating the description is invalid. I've tried looking at API documentation, but no matter what value I provide, I get back the error.

I've tried passing the  value as "PRIM", "Prim", "Primary" and various others, but have had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlake and CIF20/20 support the following values for element EmailType:

- Primary E-Mail
- Secondary E-Mail